# Regex: match word breaks that are not "="

Tags: ruby, regex

How does one match all `\b` that are not "="?

```
"igloo".match(...) # => `igloo`
"igloo=".match(...) # => `nil`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `\b` doesn't match '='; it matches on the boundary between '=' and something else.  To match only when the other side of the boundary is not '=', use a negative lookahead:

```
  rx = /igloo\b(?!=)/

 "igloo".match(rx) => #<MatchData "igloo">
 "igloo=".match(rx) => nil
```

That says "match a \b boundary, but only when not followed by '='".